# How to properly export symbols to DLL with MinGW

Tags: c, dll, mingw, mingw-w64, dllexport

I want to export specific symbols to a dynamic library for Windows and hide the others.

My simple example is as follows (running on Mac M2 and brew-installed mingw-64):

test.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

DLL_EXPORT void exported_function(void) {
    printf("This is an exported function\n");
}

void private_function(void) {
    printf("This is a private function\n");
}
```

Build

```bash
$ brew install mingw-w64
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c test.c -fvisibility=hidden -shared -O3 -s -o test.dll
$ nm test.dll
         U __imp___acrt_iob_func
         U __mingw_vfprintf
00000050 T exported_function
00000060 T private_function
```

Why is the `private_function` visible? What am I missing?

Edit: Tried `-Wl,--exclude-all-symbols`, does not work

Edit2: `-Wl,--exclude-all-symbols -Wl,--retain-symbols-file=test.sym` works, still wondering why declspec doesn't do the trick.

test.sym

```
exported_function
```

Edit3: This works as well:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared -O3 -s test.c -o test.dll
& strings test.dll | grep private_function || echo "Private function not visible"
```

Comment: One option is to use a .def file instead of __declspec(dllexport). A .def file is fine for C exports, but not so great for C++ name-mangled exports.

Comment: `nm` does not show the DLL exports. You need a tool that can examine PE format files.

Comment: Possible tools you can use are `winedump -j export file.dll` (from Wine), `rabin2 -s file.dll`  (from Radare2), or the `python3 -m pefile exports file.dll` from the Python pefile module. (See https://www.baeldung.com/linux/exported-symbols-dll .)

Comment: Thank you, this does in fact work: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared -O3 -s test.c -o test.dll && strings test.dll | grep private_function || echo "Private function not visible"`

Comment: Don't forget to create a header file that defines `DLL_EXPORT` as `__declspec(dllimport)` when calling your shared library functions. I have created a minimal/skeleton project (which is also cross platform) at https://github.com/brechtsanders/ci-test to illustrate how you can do this.